# Revoke MySQL DB Privileges on Date

Tags: python, mysql

I have been tasked with creating a simple HTML webpage to allow sysadmins to grant database permissions in a mysql instance (v 5.6.34).

Where I am stuck is that our security team wants the sysadmins to be able to enter a number of days, after which time the privs would be revoked -- I cannot seem to figure out a way to do this natively, from within the database (i.e. an expiration date of sorts), and have it happen automatically on said date.  Is there a way to do this?

I do plan to script the events in Python, but I am pretty new there as well so if I am missing something simple please let me know.

Comment: Are cronjobs (on Linux) or the task scheduler (Windows) an option?

Comment: Cronjobs are an option, yes.  I thought about writing that expiration date and user to a table, then using a cron to circle back once a day and REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES on anyone with a past expiration, but I wasn't sure if there was a better solution.